# Spring Boot singleton get Value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, singleton

Hello i am beginner in JAVA Spring Boot. 
I can't get value from aplication.yml or get from service(JpaRepository) in singleton class

```
@Component
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public class AuthProviderService {

    @Value("${test.value}")
    private String testvalue;

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;
}
```

Comment: You should add log there, or explain better that the issue is.

Comment: Maybe add your yaml file too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring boot is loading properties in particular way. Please check for spelling mistake in filename (ap**p**lication.yaml)

- 14.Application properties outside of your packaged jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
- 15.Application properties packaged inside your jar (application.properties and YAML variants).

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Also, please consider encapsulating you're configuration to @ConfigurationProperties